# Ansible: ERROR! 'shell' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

```yaml
---
 - name: Extract PS output.
   shell: "ps -ef | grep pmon"
   register: pmon

 - name: Display PS output.
   debug:
     msg:
      - "{{ pmon.stdout_lines }}"
```

Error:

```yaml
ERROR! 'shell' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/root/ansible_code/roles/sample_exercise/tasks/extractPS.yml': line 2, column 4, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
 - name: Extract PS output.
   ^ here
```

Please advise on this error.

Command I am running:

```yaml
[root@ansiblehost tasks]# pwd
/root/ansible_code/roles/sample_exercise/tasks
[root@ansiblehost tasks]# ansible-playbook -i /root/ansible_code/inventory.ini  /root/ansible_code/roles/sample_exercise/tasks/extractPS.yml --syntax-check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a syntax error. It will not happen with a minimal example like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Extract PS output.
    shell: 
      cmd: "ps -ef | grep pmon"
    register: pmon

  - name: Display PS output.
    debug:
      msg: "{{ pmon.stdout_lines }}"
```

You may take advantage from

**Further Documentation**

- [Ansible concepts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/getting_started/basic_concepts.html)
- [Ansible playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html)

Comment: Hi @U880D Thank you very much! It works.